# How to launch an application as separate instance when using a custom URI scheme?

Tags: windows, installation, registry, uri

I have an application that is using a custom URI scheme, meaning that if I go into a web browser and type in myapp:arg1=myargvalue, I'm able to start my application called myapp and it will have the arguments I supplied.

My only concern is that if an instance of myapp was already running, that instance is overwritten when I go to the same URI again. I would prefer that a new instance were created instead. Is there a way to do this?

I've read the documentation for this functionality at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa767914(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN, and the structure of my app in the registry matches what is shown in the example shown on that page, minus the name of the app:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
   alert
      (Default) = "URL:Alert Protocol"
      URL Protocol = ""
      DefaultIcon
         (Default) = "alert.exe,1"
      shell
         open
            command
               (Default) = "C:\Program Files\Alert\alert.exe" "%1"
```

Answer (score 1):

A second invocation of the same uri will create a new process instance of the same EXE.  That's the default behavior.  Unless you have some custom behavior to make a single instance process, you will get multiple instances.

Here's a sample application that you can use as an example:

```
using System;

namespace Alert
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Command line: {0}", Environment.CommandLine);
      Console.WriteLine("Process Id: {0}", System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id);
      Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }
}
```

[image: Output of 3 invocations with the same uri]

Comment: That makes sense as default behavior. I just need to figure out why I'm not seeing that default behavior.

Comment: Wondering if there is any special single instance checking going on. Are you able to launch multiple instances of your application normally from explorer or CLI?

Comment: Yes, I am able to do so from windows explorer or the CLI. However, when I open the application via the custom URI, the old instance is overwritten.

Comment: Perhaps there's some difference in how we are invoking the URI.  I invoked it from Run dialog.  Is that doing the right thing for you?